# how to script MKDIR and install .bat

Tags: batch-file, installation, mkdir

nerds and pro´s.

I am trying to get my head around a simple thing like this:

```
@echo off
MKDIR "C:\Program Files (x86)\Start-proTM" (
    IF %ERRORLEVEL0%(
        GOTO :ok
    )
    IF %ERRORLEVEL1%(
        GOTO :no
    )
)
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Start-proTM" (
    GOTO :ok
) ELSE (
    MKDIR "C:\Program Files (x86)\Start-proTM"
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL%=0 (
    GOTO :ok
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL%=1 (
    GOTO :no
)
@ECHO off

:ok
    ECHO Ok...
    pause

:no
    ECHO NO...
    Pause
```

don´t mind the rand. PAUSE, 
just to simplyfy things.

:ok REM would be rewritten to take care of the install process.
:no REM is the %ERRORLEVEL% return in txt for the user.

Just want a simple .exe to MKDIR, check if such has been created. Then install(extract) the files in set directory. And let the user know the current status of the install process, through promt in cmd.exe

Anyone? any suggestions?
I might be totally blinded, by the simplicity of the structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done something like this before:

```
set "TARGETPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Start-proTM"
echo Extracting files to %TARGETPATH%

if exist "%TARGETPATH%" (rmdir "%TARGETPATH%" /S /Q || exit /b 1)
mkdir "%TARGETPATH%" || exit /b 1
```

Note: If you try to set and use variables inside a parenthetical scope, you will need to do `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and surround the variable names with exclamation (!) points instead of percent (%) signs.